# Edits that have been made with Mac OSX Preview are invisible in Latex document

Tags: pdftex, mac

I have edited a PDF document (it actually is an image) with the program "Preview" on Mac OSX. When i open the PDF ordinary i can see the edits I made. I actually just added some white boxes to the image to cover some parts of it and I added some text here and there. Now I included this document in my Latex document via

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{Grafiken/image}
\centering
\caption{image}
\label{fig:image}
\end{figure}
```

and everything works fine when I compile it with PDFLaTeX except that I can't see the changes I made, but the image in it's original shape. Does anyone know what's wrong here?

Comment: You can edit something with a previewer? Check with another pdf-viewing tool if you see the changes.

Comment: Preview is just the name of the default program to open pictures of all formats, pdfs and many other files on mac. And yes, you can do some editing with it, like cutting off parts, adding arrows and other shapes and adding text. Do you have any suggestion which PDF-tool i could use to make those changes as easy as possible? The tool has to be compatible with mac.

Comment: I am not a mac user, i cannot make suggestions. Have you checked if the changes are visible with another pdf-viewer?

Comment: If you "Export" the PDF (File menu) then it should work okay. Preview makes non-destructive changes which need to be "flattened" into the image before normal PDF workflows will see them.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem! If you make this an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: @WillRobertson ^^^^^^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you "Export" the PDF (File menu) then it should work okay. Preview makes non-destructive changes which need to be "flattened" into the image before normal PDF workflows will see them.